# StackOverflowError occured as using java.util.regex.Matcher

Tags: java, regex

I try to catch text by Regular Expression. I list codes as follows.

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("<@a>(?:.|\\s)+?</@a>"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(fileContents.toString());
while(m.find()) {
    //Error will be thrown at this point
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

If the length of text I want to catch is too long, system will throw me a StackOverflowError.
 Otherwise, the codes work well.
 Please help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: How large is `fileContents.toString()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot and `\s` both match whitespace characters. That might lead to unnecessary backtracking. What *do* you want to match? Probably any character, including linebreaks?

Then just use the lazy dot with the dot-matches-newlines option enabled:

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("<@a>.+?</@a>", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

You are aware that you'll run into trouble if `<@a>` tags can be nested in your input?

Comment: In fact, the backtrack points are probably what is causing the stack overflow.

Comment: That's what I meant to imply (without having seen the text that is to be matched). Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score -1):

```
I always try to search text with case insensitive..
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("<@a>.+?</@a>", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```